# Azure Search - import data from one field in a database record to two fields in a Search document

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We've created an Azure Search index as such:

```
{  
  "name": "Ident0012",  
  "fields": [  
    {  
      "name": "CaptureId",  
      "type": "Edm.String",  
      "searchable": false,  
      "filterable": false,  
      "sortable": false,  
      "facetable": false,  
      "key": true,  
      "retrievable": true
    },
    {  
      "name": "Identifier",  
      "type": "Edm.String",  
      "searchable": true,  
      "filterable": false,  
      "sortable": false,  
      "facetable": false,  
      "key": false,  
      "retrievable": true,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene"
    },
    {  
      "name": "Identifier_phonetic",  
      "type": "Edm.String",  
      "searchable": true,  
      "filterable": false,  
      "sortable": false,  
      "facetable": false,  
      "key": false,  
      "retrievable": true,
         "analyzer":"name_analyzer"
    }
```

Other data that is not relevant to this question had been omitted.

We import our data from our Azure SQL Database - the columns in the database are CaptureId and Identifier.  We do not have a column in the database called Identifier_phonetic.  What we are trying to accomplish is to import the data from the database Identifier column into the Azure Search index, into both the Identifier field **and** the Identifier_phonetic field, a one-to-many mapping if you will.  We simply need duplicate information in the two fields.

The documentation is not clear on how to accomplish this.  Would appreciate some guidance from MS personnel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **field mappings** feature to "fork" a field from the datasource into two (or more) fields in your search index. Field mappings are not yet exposed in the Azure portal, so you need to create or update them using the APIs.

For details, see [Field mappings in Azure Search indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings).

Comment: Thanks Eugene, we'll give this a shot.